# If two hermitian matricies commute, do they share an orthonormal eigenbasis?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

Heads up: I'm a physicist.

I know that if $A=A^\dagger$, $B=B^\dagger$ commute ($AB=BA$) then *there is* an eigenbasis $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ which diagonalises both $A$ and $B$ even if they are degenerate.

Is it always possible to find a common eigenbasis that is **also** orthonormal, i.e. $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle =\delta_{ij}$?

What if $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric?

Comment: Do you know the proof that a hermitian matrix always has an orthonormal eigenbasis? Have you tried to transfer that proof to your problem?

Comment: @Arthur I'm aware of the fact but not the proof. I guess your comment imply that if I follow that route I should be able to prove it no?

Comment: If you read that proof, much of it should apply directly to your problem.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian The answer is yes in both cases.